# SQL: search for null date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select, null

I have a select procedure that search my Members table. 
The Members table has:

```
ID – Name –  Deleted
 1 – Marcus – NULL
 2 – Regina – 2014-03-26 09:33:00.000
```

Being: ID  a PK int no NULL, Name a varchar(250) and Deleted a datetime NULL.

Here’s my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SELECT_MEMBERS

    @ID int = NULL,
    @Name varchar(250)= NULL,
    @Deleted datetime =NULL

AS
BEGIN
 IF @Deleted = ''
        BEGIN
            SET @Deleted = NULL
        END     
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET @Deleted = @Deleted
        END

 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  ID, Name, Deleted 
    FROM dbo.Members WHERE
       (@ID IS NULL OR @ID = ID)
   AND (@Name IS NULL OR @Name = Name)
   AND (@Deleted IS NULL OR @Deleted = Deleted)


END
GO
```

In order to search for the members that have no deleted date (if they have a deleted date means that they are no active members) I do:

```
EXEC dbo.SELECT_MEMBERS  @Deleted = ''
```

But this is not working as I get the row with a deleted date inserted.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SELECT_MEMBERS

    @ID int = NULL,
    @Name varchar(250)= NULL,
    @Deleted datetime =NULL

AS
BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  ID, Name, Deleted 
    FROM dbo.Members 
    WHERE ID = ID
    AND ISNULL(@Name, '') = ISNULL(Name, '')
    AND ISNULL(@Deleted, '') = ISNULL(Deleted, '')


END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want an empty/`NULL` value for `@Deleted` date to behave differently from a `NULL` value for `@ID` and `@Name`:  you want the actual comparison for `@Deleted` to be true only when the value is `NULL`.

I think you want something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SELECT_MEMBERS
    @ID int = NULL,
    @Name varchar(250)= NULL,
    @Deleted datetime = NULL
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT ID, Name, Deleted 
   FROM dbo.Members
   WHERE (@ID IS NULL OR @ID = ID) AND
         (@Name IS NULL OR @Name = Name) AND
         ((@Deleted IS NULL  OR @Deleted = Deleted or @Deleted = '' and Deleted is null)
END;
```